# OO architecture for rendering in shader based games

Tags: oop, opengl, graphics, shader

I keep hitting this problem when building game engines where my classes want to look like this:

```
interface Entity {
  draw();
}

class World {
  draw() {
    for (e in entities)
      e.draw();
  }
}
```

That's just pseudo-code to show roughly how the drawing happens. Each entity subclass implements its own drawing. The world loops through all the entities in no particular order and tells them to draw themselves one by one.

But with shader based graphics, this tends to be horribly inefficient or even infeasible. Each entity type is probably going to have its own shader program. To minimize program changes, all entities of each particular type need to be drawn *together*. Simple types of entities, like particles, may also want to aggregate their drawing in other ways, like sharing one big vertex array. And it gets really hairy with blending and such where some entity types need to be rendered at certain times relative to others, or even at multiple times for different passes.

What I normally end up with is some sort of renderer singleton for each entity class that keeps a list of all instances and draws them all at once. That's not so bad since it separates the drawing from the game logic. But the renderer needs to figure out which subset of entities to draw and it needs access to multiple different parts of the graphics pipeline. This is where my object model tends to get messy, with lots of duplicate code, tight coupling, and other bad things.

So my question is: what is a good architecture for this kind of game drawing that is efficient, versatile, and modular?

Comment: The fact that you're separating it from everything else is good to start out with, and it sounds like its messy because its… well… _messy_. **Necessary** mess is unfortunate, but still necessary. But I doubt you'll view this as an answer…

Answer (score 8):

Use a two stages approach: First loop through all entities, but instead of drawing let them insert references to themself into a (the) drawing batch list. Then sort the list by OpenGL state and shader use; after sorting insert state changer objects at every state transistion.

Finally iterate through the list executing the drawing routine of each object referenced in the list.

Comment: what if you have different engines? OpenGL,DirectX ?

Comment: @Parhs: Neither OpenGL nor DirectX are engines. They are APIs. And this first stage called "frame setup" is usually done in parts by the renderer code that talks to the API and in part by the scene management code. For example frustum culling is something the scene code is better suited for, texture and shader state should be sorted by the renderer code. Also you don't have to do everything in one pass. It's perfectly fine to first traverse (in the scene code) over all bounding boxes to to frustum culling and sorting by depth. Then hand this list to the renderer for further refinement.

Comment: Thank you for responding. However my problem is here.You said " executing the drawing routine of each object" . What if you want to use multiple APIs (direct2d,opengl etc) ? I mean draw() within each object should have implementation for all api ? Or renderer take care of drawing too ?

Comment: @Parhs: Well, of course you should not mix the renderer code into the scene management code. Think of it as a visitor pattern: For every object the renderer code asks the scene/object code to give it the relevant data (meshes, texture IDs and so on; that data is already used during the frame setup) and then uses that data to do the actual drawing. And for each API you want to support you implement a different render code path. While this extra work might be repelling at first, it allows to to make the best use of the API it is addressing.

Comment: That could be implemented in different classes   OpenGLRenderer DirectXRenderer etc ?

Comment: @Parhs: Yes; normally you'd have a set of "Renderer" virtual functions which you implement for each render path you want to support. With the scene class-es being either friends to the renderer or the `*Renderer` being a visitor to the scene classes.

Comment: Hmm visitor pattern seems interesting. However I want to apply these to a 2D application so I would have to deal with a bit different stuff

Answer (score 1):

This is not an easy question to answer, since there are many ways to deal with the problem. A good idea is to look into some Game/Rendering engines and see how this is handled there. A good starting point would be [Ogre](http://www.ogre3d.org/), since its well documented and open source.

As far as I know, it separates the vertex data from the material components (shaders) through the built-in material scripts. The renderer itself knows what mesh is to be drawn in what order and with what shader (and its passes).

I know this answer is a bit vague, but I hope I could give you a useful hint.